# Synchronized ArrayList for two threads - write and read

Tags: java, list, concurrency

I need to solve this problem. I have console app in which I am inserting some String values. The console app is still running, user can add more and more entries and every 1 minute, there should be another Thread which will print some List statistic (e.g. size etc.). When I use Main Thread for user's console and different Thread for counting and printing this statistic data to the console (both working with the same List). It is enough to use:

```
List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Or I need to user volatile and access the List in the synchronized block as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes! it is enough. You can also use classes in `java.util.concurrent`

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with the list.

`Collections.synchronizedList(...)` simply wraps every method with a synchronized block, synchronizing on itself. The synchronization starts when the invoked method starts executing, and stops when it stops executing.

Notionally, it the list is wrapped like this:

```
class SynchronizedList<T> implements List<T> {
  private List<T> delegate;

  @Override public int size() {
    synchronized (this) {
      return delegate.size();
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

As such, doing simple things like `list.size()`, `list.add(...)`, `list.get(...)` don't require any further synchronization.

However, if you want to do more complex things, for example iterating the list, yes, you need additional synchronization:

```
synchronized (list) {
  for (String s : list) { ... }
}
```

This is because the synchronization stops as soon as the hidden call to `list.iterator()` completes; hence, other threads would be able to modify the list while you are iterating.

Comment: I am about to iterate over the array once in a minute and count the sum or do some statistics, but I need to iterate it and calculate some result. Meantime the application should be able to serve the client console. So I think the synchronized block is the right choice for me?

Comment: @vviston yes, probably. You can get away without explicit synchronization if you extract the elements using `toArray()` (which is synchronized for a `synchronizedList`); but if you want to avoid the copy, you need external synchronization.